# create a project in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, new-project

After installing intelliJ IDEA, when I create a new project, I'm presented with this:

[image]

But those pages should be opened with JAVA EE :

[image]

Should I install anything else?

Comment: it depends on what type of project you want to create... there is no single answer for this question unless you provide more details

Comment: I see similar picture when creating a new project and think it's perfectly fine. Your second picture, is it the same version of IntelliJ?

Comment: first photo is My intellij and second photo that is installed on my workplace computer.

now how a creat a new project in intellija?

Comment: My problem is that I act according to this tutorial to create a project [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html?origin=old_help), The training in the second phase, there is no such thing as JAVA EE in my software ...undrestand dear?

Comment: Probably you have different versions of IDEA? Click in `about`

Comment: The problem may be that I am using version 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

Edit.: Understood what you mean - I managed to restore some of the sections in the Java by enabling corresponding plugins: Hibernate, Google App Engine, etc.

So, you need to do the same and enable plugins that you want.

Comment: Where can I download the plugin? And how do I enable plugins?

Comment: Open menu: Settings > Plugins

Comment: thanks but My problem is that I act according to this tutorial to create a project [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html?origin=old_help), The training in the second phase, there is no such thing as JAVA EE in my software ...

Comment: for that tutorial you don't need any of those Java EE sections in the Java section - the tutorial says it will build 'plain old java application', which means a java application with a main class and no EE components

Comment: if you want a similar look, try enabling Glassfish intergration plugin in the plugins section.

Comment: The problem may be that I am using version 30 days?

Comment: No, 30 days evaluation version is still a full ultimate version with all the features. You just need to enable the plugins, as I wrote before: Open menu "Settings", then find there "Plugins", then choose JavaEE plugins and Glassfish and other with the same name as in the 2nd picture - you'll then see a similar screen.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand, you don't see the Java EE plugin in your version of intellij.. if it is the case, i think you have to continue ( Next till your project opens). once it's done go to File -> Settings ->Plugins. 
you should see this.
[Java EE plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNnaD.png). 
this is the list of plugins you need.

Comment: The problem may be that I am using version 30 days?